# Выравнивание в таблице не работает с картинками

Tags: html

Почему параметр тега `<td>` `valign` перестаёт действовать после вставки картинки?

```html
<table width='168' border='0' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='font:bold 10px \"Arial\"; color:#375cc7; border: solid 1px #999999;'>

  <tr>
    <td height='48' valign='middle' style='border-bottom: solid 1px #999999;'>техт$техт</td>
    <td valign='middle' style='border-bottom: solid 1px #999999;'>$dollar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='48' valign='middle'>техт
      <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/siena/32x32/currency_euroblue.png'>техт</td>
    <td valign='middle'>$euro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такова специфика тега img. Добавь к нему атрибут valign="middle"

```
<table width='168' border='0' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='font:bold 10px \"Arial\"; color:#375cc7; border: solid 1px #999999;'>

  <tr>
    <td height='48' valign='middle' style='border-bottom: solid 1px #999999;'>техт$техт</td>
    <td valign='middle' style='border-bottom: solid 1px #999999;'>$dollar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='48' valign='middle'>техт
      <img valign="middle" src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/siena/32x32/currency_euroblue.png'>техт</td>
    <td valign='middle'>$euro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Осмелюсь заметить, что у тега "img" разве есть атрибут "valign"?
Странно это, но ваш код работает.  
Я добавил к нему [align='absmiddle']